# Devise a formula inside a loop for x and y to satisfy these requirements

Tags: java, c++, c, math

Given the following requirements, devise a formula to find x and y as given below

```
given:  length1   length2, assume length1 >= length2
total = length1 + length2


i = 0                : x = 0,          y = 0
i = 1                : x = 0,          y = 1
...
i = length2 -1       : x = 0,          y = length2 -1
i = total-length1    : x = 0,          y = 0
i = total-length1 +1 : x = 1,          y = 0
...
i = length1 + length2: x = length1 -1, y = 0
```

So in code, it would look something like:

```
int length1 = //given
int length2 = //given
int total = length1 + length2;
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    x = ?  //answer here
    y = ?  //answer here
}
```

Here is an example when length1 = 5; length2 =4

```
 i   x,y
---------
i=0  0,0 
i=1  0,1  
i=2  0,2
i=3  0,3
i=4  0,0
i=5  1,0  
i=6  2,0  
i=7  3,0  
i=8  4,0
```

edit:
I'm looking for a 1-liner for finding x and y.
Something that divides x out to 0 when i is less than length2 and y to 0 when i is > length1.

Comment: Why all the down votes and close votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (i < length2) {
  x = 0;
  y = i;
} else {
  x = i - length2;
  y = 0;
}
```

Comment: lol, 4min too slow. But I like how our solutions are identical :D

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
if (i < length2) {
    x = 0;
    y = i;
} else {
    x = i - length2;
    y = 0;
}
```